# How to add a class to element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using a jQuery code snippet to scan dynamic text (.price-tag) and then use that text to add a class to an element (.w-dyn-item -> .w-dyn-item free).

My problem is that I not only have a .price-tag, but also a .type-tag .color-tag .shape-tag and I'd like to change the code so that it scans the text of all of these classes and then adds all of them as classes to w-dyn-item (.w-dyn-item -> .w-dyn-item free book green circle)

I would appreciate any help <3

```
<div class="courses-list-item w-dyn-item free">

<div class="price-tag">Free</div>

<div class="type-tag">Book</div>

<div class="color-tag">Green</div>

<div class="shape-tag">Circle</div>

</div>
```

```
jQuery
( '.w-dyn-item .price-tag' ).each
(
    function( index, element )
    {
        var _this = jQuery( element );
            _this.parent().addClass( _this.text().toLowerCase() );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can give your inner div's a common class to iterate over and grab the class name you want to use. Note you don't have to use a class like `.item`. You could say `$('.w-dyn-item div')`, but that's not very specific and would grab any and all divs that you have inside the parent.

```js
$('.w-dyn-item .item').each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).parent().addClass($(this).text().toLowerCase());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="courses-list-item w-dyn-item">
  <div class="item price-tag">Free</div>
  <div class="item type-tag">Book</div>
  <div class="item color-tag">Green</div>
  <div class="item shape-tag">Circle</div>
</div>
```

Use your inspect tool to see all the new classes added to `w-dyn-item`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b2m4eujc/